# Вызов функции в чужом процессе, который написан на .net / C#

Tags: c#, winapi, dll, reverse-engineering

Есть задача выполнить статический метод в чужом .net приложении. Как это реализовать наиболее простым и удобным способом? Статически редактировать код в чужом приложении нельзя.

**Итак, есть два процесса:**

1. Моё приложение на c#/.net. Могу менять исходный код, запускать с любыми правами.
2. Чужое приложение тоже написанное на .net, не могу менять исходный код. В этом приложении есть статический класс, статический метод, который мне нужно вызвать. Могу запускать с любыми правами.

**Я ищу информацию и пытаюсь подобрать самый удобный и правильный вариант. Мои общие вопросы и предположения:**

- Можно написать dll и заинжектить её в процесс, но встает вопрос, а можно ли написать такую dll на c# или это доступно только на C/C++, а если это не C#, то как написать вызов статического метода из чужого языка?
- Возможно можно просто вызвать через WinAPI createremotethread,
  выделить память, внедрить код и вызвать метод который мне необходим?
- Какие данные
  необходимо знать чтобы вызвать статический метод из памяти другого
  процесса, адрес начала метода в памяти?

  Если есть простой пример, то он очень поможет. Или если у вас есть опыт в решении подобных задач, то напишите алгоритм действий. Спасибо

Comment: Вы можете загрузить чужой модуль, как библиотеку, и безжалосно пользовать всю его начинку через рефлексию.

Comment: @nick_n_a, наверное так не получится. Потому-что мне важно состояние статического объекта, который находится в куче чужого процесса. Т.е. если я загружу чужой модуль к себе в процесс, как библиотеку и при обращению к нужному мне статическому методу скомпилируется новый объект в адресном пространстве моего процесса и он НЕ будет иметь общего состояния с тем объектом, который мне нужен. Тот метод который я хочу вызывать, он содержит в себе переменные/ссылки на состояние статического объекта, который  находится в памяти чужого процесса.

Comment: Сдаётся мне, что любой антивирус подобную активность примет за вирусную атаку. Сейчас вообще по-моему уже даже на уровне процессоров внедрили защиту, чтобы одни процессы не могли лазить в память других процессов. Это мягко говоря довольно не безопасная активность.

Comment: @CrazyElf, пускай принимает. Это сознательное решение. Если будут проблемы с антивирусом, то могу отключить или внести в исключения.

Comment: Вполне может оказаться, что это запрещено на уровне ОС или даже на хардварном уровне процессором. Зря вы в эту сторону копаете, мне кажется. Нужно сделать так, чтобы у того процесса был легальный интерфейс, через который можно общаться.

Comment: @CrazyElf Действие любого отладчика основано на работе с памятью чужого процесса. В ОС, конечно, есть функционал для предотвращения этого, но он работает только для определенных процессов (системных или работающих с мультимедиа - для обеспечения DRM), а не для всех. В роли легального интерфейса в .NET выступает CLR Debugging API.

Comment: Грубым внедрением кода тут задачу не решить, ведь чтобы запустить управляемый метод, нужно связаться с CLR. Смотрите в сторону [ICorDebugEval2::CallParameterizedFunction](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/debugging/icordebugeval2-callparameterizedfunction-method). Здесь есть ссылки на примеры, как начать работать с CLR Debugging API: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jmstall/how-can-i-use-icordebug